# Using React MUI editable datagrid, I need to find a way to dynamically add new columns through the UI via a button click

Tags: mui-x-data-grid

I'm able to follow the MUI example for editable tables:

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=Demo.js

But once I add a feature to allow a user to add a new column via adding a new column name in a text box, then hitting "add a new column"  I keep getting errors from the npm MUI package itself regarding columns lengths.

How can I allow a user of my site to add a column to the stackblitz code above?